# Can cell mediated immune response be transferred via blood transfusion

Tags: cell-biology, virology, immune-system

I read that human body can develop cell mediated immunity to viral infections and subsequently clear the virus. For example, people clear warts through cell mediated immune response against the wart virus. Is it then possible to transfer the blood from one person to another to transfer the type of immune cells that kill the virus?

Comment: May you consider to add some refferences to your conclusion?